# Filling the null values of a column based on a column with equal values

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table as below:

| customerId | orderNo | transactionCode | transactionSubCode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123123123 | ABC-1234 | null | null |
| 123123123 | XYZ-123 | null | null |
| 123123123 | DEF-456 | null | null |
| 123123123 | HYT-111 | 12a8ksabbc | 999123xxxx11 |
| 123123123 | ZZZ-999 | null | null |
| 333333334 | XYC-777 | null | null |
| 333333334 | XYZ-331 | null | null |
| 333333334 | XYZ-334 | 13a7kcssaf | null |
| 333333334 | XYZ-655 | null | 76612yyyas33 |

I would like to distribute the existing value on the **transactionSubCode** column to all of the null values of the same column, based on a column that has the same value, which is **customerId** in our case. So the final table will have results like below:

| customerId | orderNo | transactionCode | transactionSubCode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123123123 | ABC-1234 | null | 999123xxxx11 |
| 123123123 | XYZ-123 | null | 999123xxxx11 |
| 123123123 | DEF-456 | null | 999123xxxx11 |
| 123123123 | HYT-111 | 12a8ksabbc | 999123xxxx11 |
| 123123123 | ZZZ-999 | null | 999123xxxx11 |
| 333333334 | XYC-777 | null | 76612yyyas33 |
| 333333334 | XYZ-331 | null | 76612yyyas33 |
| 333333334 | XYZ-334 | 13a7kcssaf | 76612yyyas33 |
| 333333334 | XYZ-655 | null | 76612yyyas33 |

I have tried self-joining with different approaches but never managed to get the desired result in any case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a window function:

```
select t.* (except transactionSubCode),
       max(transactionSubCode) over (partition by customerId) as transactionSubCode
from t;
```

Comment: That answer sir, was super fast. Thank you!